# Devexpress DxValidateProvidor validate

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to check whether the value entered in a DevExpress Control is empty, but my Validation always returns false. For this reason, I am unable to perform further operations.

If you can help I'd appreciate it.

```
 public static class ValidateHelpers {
        public static bool validate(Form f, params Control[] control) {
            bool result = true;
            if (control != null) {
                KgsDxValidationProvider prov = new KgsDxValidationProvider { ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Auto };
                ConditionValidationRule notEmptyValidationRule = new ConditionValidationRule {
                    ConditionOperator = ConditionOperator.IsNotBlank,
                    ErrorText = "You Must Enter A Value",
                    ErrorType = ErrorType.Critical
                };

                foreach (var item in control) {
                    prov.SetValidationRule(item, notEmptyValidationRule);
                    result = false;
                }
                f.ValidateChildren();

            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why should your method return true? You always set the value to false expect the case where control is null.

Comment: I think you need to set result to the result of f.ValidateChildren();

Comment: Could be. and yet we do not get the results I have the right as a result of this deal Workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to validate all childrens on your form. This will do what you want:

```
private bool Validate(params Control[] controls)
{
   bool result = controls == null || !controls.Any();

   if (controls != null)
   {
       DXValidationProvider provider = new DXValidationProvider { ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Auto };
       ConditionValidationRule noEmptyValues = new ConditionValidationRule
       {
           ConditionOperator = ConditionOperator.IsNotBlank,
           ErrorText = @"You must enter a value",
           ErrorType = ErrorType.Critical
       };

       foreach (Control control in controls)
       {
          provider.SetValidationRule(control, noEmptyValues);
       }

       result = provider.Validate(); //Validate all controls associated with the provider
    }

   return result;
 }
```

If you need further assistance for custom validation etc. you can check this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsDXErrorProviderDXValidationProvidertopic).